# Extend/wrap an object ad-hoc with more functionality

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, software-design

The following question adresses a problem I often encounter. Basically, there are solutions like the adaptor pattern, but I find it a bit unsatisfying.

Suppose I have a class `Polygon` which implements an - uhm - polygon with quite some functionality. Many of those `Polygon` live in my program, some as lonely variables, some in collection structures.

Now, there's a function that needs an argument type that is basically a Polygon, but with some additional features. Let's say, a `Polygon` who can return some metrics: his volume, center of gravity, and angular mass. Plus, the function also needs the methods of the original `Polygon`.

A **first idea** is:

```
class Polygon:
# defines my polygon

class PolygonWithMetrics(Polygon):
# - extends polygon with the metrics
# - takes Polygon as argument upon construction
# - would need to delegate many functions to Polygon

def functionUsingPolygonWithMetrics(p):
# use functions of Polygon and PolygonWithMetrics

# driving code:
p = Polygon(some args here)
... more code ...
p_with_metrics = PolygonWithMetrics(p) # Bummer - problem here...
functionUsingPolygonWithMetrics(p_with_metrics)
```

The **problem**: It would require to delegate many many functions from `PolygonWithMetrics` into the original `Polygon`.

A **second idea** is:

```
class Polygon:
# defines my polygon

class PolygonMetrics:
# takes a polygon and provides metrics methods on it

def functionUsingPolygonWithMetrics(p):
# use functions of Polygon and PolygonMetrics

# driving code:
p = Polygon(some args here)
... more code ...
p_with_metrics = PolygonMetrics(p)
functionUsingPolygonWithMetrics(p, p_with_metrics) # Bummer - problem here...
```

This idea takes the original `Polygon` as an argument, plus a second object that provides the metrics functions. The problem is that I would need to change the signature of `functionUsingPolygonWithMetrics`.

What I would really need is an idea how to extend an existing object ad-hoc with some more functionality, without the problems given in idea 1 and 2.

I could imagine an idea roughly like this, where the job is mostly done by `PolygonWithMetrics`:

```
class Polygon:
# defines my polygon

class PolygonWithMetrics(maybe inherits something):
# - takes a Polygon and provides metrics methods on it
# - upon construction, it will take a polygon
# - will expose the full functionality of Polygon automatically

def functionUsingPolygonWithMetrics(p):
# use functions of Polygon and PolygonWithMetrics

# driving code:
p = Polygon(some args here)
... more code ...
p_with_metrics = PolygonWithMetrics(p)
functionUsingPolygonWithMetrics(p)
```

Three **questions** arise:

- Does this pattern have sort of a name?
- Is it a good idea, or should I resort to some more adviced techniques?
- How to do it in Python?

Comment: Could you have a second class `PolygonWithMetrics` that provided all the necessary methods and copies all relevant data from `Polygon` in the `__init__` method? You would essentially create a new object. I guess that is your option 3.

Comment: Why not simply extend your original `Polygon` class to provide all functionality?

Comment: @TammoHeeren: Your first suggestion (as mentioned in the question) would mean a lot of manual copying/delegating. The second suggestion would mean to change a class that I might not want to change (or might not want to make any larger). Imagine a case where I have twenty such function-extending classes and three implementations of Polygon...

Comment: Well, something got to give. Either you make the changes everywhere they are needed, or you do it in the class. I would probably do it in the class, but I don't know your code.

Comment: Have a look at mixins. They provide a nice way to extend/ overwrite class methods.

Comment: @TammoHeeren: The problem mentioned in idea 1 does not disappear with mixins. Furthermore, I *might* have to change some of the existing code, but I think it's always a good design approach to first check for solutions that require *no* changes in existing and (so far) sound code.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your problem, but it sounds to me like you want to change things without changing things. Your option 3 (mentioned in my first comment) seems to be what you need.

Comment: After all, I think, I have a solution for the problem: The idea is to create a class PolygonDelegator that *has* a Polygon p and *inherits* the interface of Polygon. It will then override all inherited methods so that they will delegate to the Polygon p. This class can be inherited to all classes similiar to PolygonWithMetrics. So PolygonWithMetrics has full Polygon functionality, plus additional metrics, plus does not have to delegate manually to Polygon.